# foreach loop repeating the iteration

Tags: php, mysql

I am importing products using xml, here is my code

```
$allLangs = Language::getLanguages(true,1,false);
$totalLangs = sizeof($allLangs);
$url = "XMLUrl";
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = utf8_encode($xml);
$xml = preg_replace('/&(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/', '&amp;', $xml);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach ($xml->item as $key => $item) {
  $sql10 = "SELECT id FROM product WHERE reference='$item->reference'";
  $res10 = Db::getInstance()->getValue($sql10);

  if (empty($res10)) {
    for ($i=0; $i < $totalLangs; $i++) {
      if($allLangs[$i]['iso_code'] == "en") { 
        $dname[$allLangs[$i]['id_lang']] = trim($item->name);
      }else {
        $dtname = translate(trim($item->name) , "en" , $allLangs[$i]['iso_code']);
        $dname[$allLangs[$i]['id_lang']] = $dtname; 
      }
    }
    $product = New Product();
    $product->name = $dtname;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    $product->save();
  }
}
```

function translate()

```
function translate($phrase, $from ="en", $to = "de"){
    $apiKey = '<ApiKey>';
    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=' . $apiKey . '&q=' . rawurlencode($phrase) . '&source='.$from.'&target='.$to;

    $handle = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($handle);                 
    $responseDecoded = json_decode($response, true);
    curl_close($handle);

    return $responseDecoded['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];
}
```

My xml contains more that 3500 products, in foreach loop first i am checking if the product exist or not, if not then translate the name and description by sending request to google translation API and after translating insert the product in database. As per the code there should not be any duplicate product, but after importing there are many duplicate (7,8 or 9) enteries  with the same reference number in the database.

**1** Why its insertign multiple product with the same reference number as i am validating at the top in foreach loop?

**2** why loop repeating itself at first place?

Note: I have checched xml doesnt have any duplicate entry. and loop is working fine without sending request for google translation.

Comment: 1. Usage of queries inside a looping structure is not a good practice!!!

Comment: Yes, but i want to know whats the cause of this issue, as it is working fine if i remove google translation api part from the loop.

Comment: Probably I won't be able to help you, but if the loop works fine if you drop the request for the Google translation, this means that the code you posted above is correct and the problem is in the code you are using to send the request to Google API. Maybe posting this code can help someone among us to help you.

Comment: Question updated.